# c++ objects with constructors taking values into encapsulated objects

Tags: c++, object, constructor, encapsulation

I have been trying to figure out how c++ handles multiple objects, with constructors that take in values, that are set up inside of each other.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Inner {
  int myvar;
public:
  Inner(int input) {
    myvar = input;
  }

  int output() {
    return myvar;
  }
};

class Outer {
  Inner inner;
public:
  Outer(int input) {
    Inner inner(input);
  }

  int value_out() {
    return inner.output();
  }
};

int main() {
  int myvar = 0;
  Outer outer(myvar);
  cout << outer.value_out() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

My console output when I go to compile:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd Desktop
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ touch test.cpp
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ g++ test.cpp -o test
test.cpp: In constructor ‘Outer::Outer(int)’:
test.cpp:19:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘Inner::Inner()’
   Outer(int input) {
                    ^
test.cpp:19:20: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:7:3: note: Inner::Inner(int)
   Inner(int input) {
   ^
test.cpp:7:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:4:7: note: Inner::Inner(const Inner&)
 class Inner {
       ^
test.cpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$
```

I am new to c++ so just looking for better understanding on how everything falls into place. I am coming from scripting languages like python and ruby where a lot of this is done automatically. Thank you for help!

Here is what I am trying to do working in Ruby if this helps to better make it clear what I am trying to do here....

```
class Inner
  def initialize(input)
    @myvar = input
  end

  def output
    @myvar
  end
end

class Outer
  def initialize(input)
    @inner = Inner.new(input)
  end

  def value_out
    @inner.output
  end
end

myvar = 0
outer = Outer.new(0)
puts outer.value_out
```

So I guess the core of my question is How do i write an object, that has a default constructor as a member variable of another object since c++ freaks out if I assign anything to a member variable. So how does one input anything inside an object that requires an input if its a member variable of another object? Is this even possible or am I trying to do something that is incredibly stupid and bad?

Comment: `Inner() = default;` or `Inner() {}`. Also, in your constructor, you are not initializing `inner`. `Outer(int input) : inner(input)`.

Comment: Read about [member initialization lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: Trying to understand this but its just going clear over my head. Reading that article again. I tried editing the code and replacing stuff with what was posted but it just got worse for me and I got more confused. Just going to read this until I somehow grasp it, somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are a little confused about the member variable `inner` and the `inner` used in the constructor body

In your constructor body,

```
Outer(int input) {
  Inner inner(input);
}
```

The variable `inner` is not the class member. It is a local variable in the scope of the function. To initialize the class member, you will need to use:

```
Outer(int input) : inner(input) {}
```

Comment: I may need to see this all written out, I am really stupid bro, I just can't make this work. Also, would vote u up if I could....

Comment: @user3712902, no need to get disheartened. We all started out from the basics at some point. Try what makes sense from the comments to your post and this answer. It won't be too long before these become second nature.

Comment: When I put inner as "inner(input) {}" It thinks I am just trying to make a function call, does not recognize I am talking about the variable/object instance inner....

Comment: I am extreamly confused about the constant declaration of object inner, is Inner inner; wrong or should I be putting Inner inner() ? I dont even, giving up for the night.

Comment: I think I will just go back to ruby, I just can't do the same things in c++ at all....

Comment: ps nothing in here has compiled for me yet so I really have nothing that works atm

Comment: Actually I don't want to go back to ruby, I mean honestly I like writing it more but the community in BOTH python and ruby are so hostile against new coders. Asking questions about either of those languages render markdowns all the time. So far the c++ community has been way more open to new coders like myself and more helpful...

Comment: @user3712902 [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/DSSpHm). Your code rolled with member-initializers as R.Sahu describes in this answer.

Comment: Cool got it working from that, thank you. Going to read up on why I have to write Outer(int input) : inner(input)  instead of assigning it inside the constructor function body like other things. Thank you